# Grant security permission to an applet compressed into an JAR file

Tags: java, security, jdbc, jar, applet

I have created a standalone java app that uses a MySQL DB. I need to give security permissions to the applet inside the jar file. How do i do it without making the user do anything more than just a double click on the jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standalone Java application, which is not an applet, will not have a security manager present unless one is explicitly set, so permissions are not necessary. That is to say, the code will not have full permissions, but nothing should be checking anyway (it is still possible to tell the lack of permissions through `java.security.AccessController`).